# React mapping an array

Tags: reactjs

I've a object:

```
{
  "products": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "category": "Milk & meat",
      "products": {
        "product1": ["Name", "Recipe", "Photo"]
        }
    }
}
```

and it's mapped like that:

```
return (
    <div className="box list">
    {this.props.products
        .map((product, ind) =>
             <div key={ind}>
                 <h2>{product.category}</h2>
                       {Object.values(product.products).map(name => <li onClick={this.props.handleClickedProduct}>{name[0]}</li>)}
             </div>)}
    </div>
)
```

The onClick method passes the product name ([0] in array) to other component. It does it like that:

```
handleClickedProduct = (e) => {
    this.setState({ clickedProduct: e.target.innerHTML });
}
```

How cane I setState [1] and [2] from the same array?
I want to pass forward the product name and keep in state the recipe and photo.

Thanks,
Kuba

Comment: Please check this out https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
  products = [
   {
      id: 1,
      category: "Milk & meat",
      products: {
        product1: ["Name", "Recipe", "Photo"]
        }
   },
    {
      id: 2,
      category: "Milk & bread",
      products: {
        product1: ["Name", "Recipe", "Photo"]
        }
  }
  ]
  
  state = {
   clickedProduct: null
  }
  
 handleClick = (product) => (e) => {
  this.props.onClick(product)
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
     <div className="box list">
        {this.products.map((product, ind) =>
             <div key={ind}>
                 <h2>{product.category}</h2>
                       <ul>
                         {Object.values(product.products)
                          .map(pr => <li onClick={this.handleClick(pr)}>{pr[0]}</li>)}
                       </ul>
             </div>)
             }
       </div>
    )
  }
}

class Handler extends React.Component {
 handler = (e) => {
   console.log(e)
  }
  
  render () {
   return <Example onClick={this.handler}/>
  } 
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Handler />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Change `handleClickedProduct` to be

```
handleClickedProduct = (name) => (e) => {
this.setState({ clickedProduct: e.target.innerHTML });}
```

and inside your map you can just do `this.handleClickedProduct(product.products)` and use it inside the `handleClickedProduct` function.

Comment: Thanks, but can you help me bit more with using it in map and then in the function?

Comment: The important thing is that `handleClickedProduct` can be passed whatever you want so you can just pass the `product.products`.

Comment: I think I know what you mean. But handleClickedProduct is in a different component than the map.

Comment: I recived:
    function (e) {
                // this.setState({
                //     clickedProduct: e.target.innerHTML,
                // });
                console.log(name);
            }

Comment: im not sure how you are trying to call it, it would really help if you post some more code. I update the code snippet to add another component that passes the handleClicked